# mySQL и работа с не целыми числами

Tags: php, mysql

В базе данных хранятся числа типа:

```
1.00134534
```

И для сохранения точности работаю с библиотекой `BCMATH (PHP)`, если требуются какие-нибудь арифметические действия.

Собственно вопрос: правильно ли это? Много где читал, что в таких случаях, перед сохранением в БД приводят такие числа в целые и работают как с целыми, но если нужно отобразить, то приводят в нужный вид (то есть делят)...

Comment: Поясните какого типа у вас рациональные числа- с плавающей точкой или без?

Comment: Храню в формате Decimal (x,8)

Comment: *для сохранения точности работаю с библиотекой BCMATH (PHP)* Данные хранятся в MySQL. Какая разница, чем они обрабатываются в PHP? *Много где читал, что в таких случаях, перед сохранением в БД приводят такие числа в целые и работают как с целыми* Каждый имеет право создать себе кучу геморроя. Хранение зависит от задачи, а не от абстрактного ОБС.

Comment: Я считаю, что куча геморроя, это наоборот, делать что-то не обдумав... Вот так и в моей ситуации: если преобразовать числа в целые и работать как с целыми, то можно избавиться от BCMATH, так как той точности уже не нужно. Я вот и спрашиваю совета у знающих людей, что лучше и практичней

Comment: @Алексей если ваши числа (умноженные на десять в восьмой)  и результаты вычислений с ними не вылазят за прделы php int, то можете работать с ними как с целыми. Но обратите внимание, что как только они перестанут быть целыми, например при делении, вы снова будете сталкиваться с потерей точности. Поэтому всё зависит от того, что вы с этими числами делаете и какая точность вам нужна.